# not able to open link in IE using nsILocalFile

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox

this webpage is built for firefox, but it has to display a link which is to be opened in IE. So I am trying to use a code I found on [net](http://custombuttons.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1015). but it is not working. what am I missing?

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function myFunction()
    {
        alert("opening now....");
        var localFile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
        var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
        var url = content.document.location.href;
        var args = ["-new-tab", url];
        localFile.initWithPath("C:\\Program Files \(x86\)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
        process.init(localFile);
        process.run(false, args, args.length);
    }
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<p>Click the link top open in IE</p>
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="myFunction()">open in IE</a>
```

When I click on link, it opens the google page: in same window, in same borser, in same tab.Pl advice.

thank you.

Comment: You understand, I hope, that the Firefox code above only works when run as a part of a Firefox extension, and it will not work at all within a web page?

Answer (score 0):

myFunction is not defined in the global scope. Adding it to the dcoument ready callback guarantuees this.

You could move myFunction outside of the document ready callback. However:

In this case I would attach a click handler using jquery as follows

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        // do stuff
    });
})
```

Note this selects all anchors and applies the same event handler. Ideally you would use a selector.

```
$("#myGoogleLink").click(function() {

})
```

Add the id myGoogleLink to your html anchor

Comment: yes i can now execute the process, but i get error: TypeError: Components.classes is undefined
http://mywebsite/test/html_test.html
Line 88

Comment: line 88 is: var localFile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);